# Is it possible to submit a series of different jobs to slurm?

Tags: slurm

For example, I have a script called `myScript` that processes *one* input file, and I have a list of filenames. That is, I need to run

```
$ myScript <filename>
```

for a list of filenames stored in a `filenames.txt`.

The only way to distribute my jobs I found in Slurm is to specify `-n` parameter, which duplicates your command or batch script. But notice that I need to pass in a variable parameter into each run. Is it possible to do so in Slurm?

My current solution is to fire a lot of `sbatch` scripts, each with a specified `<filename>`. However, this way `squeue` will show a whole lot of my jobs and I'm afraid this is frown upon by other users.

Answer (score 4):

One option is using job arrays. Prepare a two-lines submission (untested) script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
#SBATCH --array=1-<number of lines in filenames.txt>
myScript "$(tail -n+$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID filenames.txt | head -n1)"
```

and submit it with `sbatch mySubmissionScript.sh`. It will create a [job array](http://www.schedmd.com/slurmdocs/job_array.html) with one job per line in the file, running `myScript` on the file written at line `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`. You will just need to replace `<number of lines in filenames.txt>` with the actual number of lines in the files as given by `wc -l filenames.txt` for instance.

Job arrays are shown in a compressed form in the output of Slurm `squeue` command, with all pending jobs displayed as one line only. You can also limit the number of simultaneously running jobs with

```
--array=1-16%4
```

Slurm will then only allow 4 jobs from that array at a time.