# SLURM sbatch job array for the same script but with different input string arguments run in parallel

Tags: arrays, slurm, sbatch

My question is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900600/slurm-sbatch-job-array-for-the-same-script-but-with-different-input-arguments-ru), and the difference is that my different arguments are not numbers but strings.

If I have a script (myscript.R) that takes two strings as arguments: "text-a", "text-A". My shell script for sbatch would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 12
#SBATCH -t 120:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=main
#SBATCH --export=ALL

srun ./myscript.R "text-a" "text-A"
```

Now I have a few different input strings that I'd like to run with:

```
first <- c("text-a","text-b","text-c","text-d")
second <- c("text-A","text-B","text-C","text-D")
```

and I want to run myscript.R with combinations of the texts, for example:

```
srun ./myscript.R "text-a" "text-A"
srun ./myscript.R "text-b" "text-B"
srun ./myscript.R "text-c" "text-C"
srun ./myscript.R "text-d" "text-D"
```

But if I put them in the same shell script, they'll run sequentially. I only know that I can use `#SBATCH -a 0-10` when the arguments are index. If I want to submit the four scripts at the same time and each of them with the exact same settings (especially each one need to be assigned `-c 12`), how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store de list of argument values in an array and use the `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` env variable to index that array.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 12
#SBATCH -t 120:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=main
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH --array=0-3

A=(text-{a..d}) # This is equivalent to A=(text-a text-b ... text-d)
B=(text-{A..D})

srun ./myscript.R "${A[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}" "${B[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"
```

and simply submit it with `sbatch`.