# Do I need a single bash file for each task in SLURM?

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I am trying to launch several task in a SLURM-managed cluster, and would like to avoid dealing with dozens of files.
Right now, I have 50 tasks (subscripted i, and for simplicity, i is also the input parameter of my program), and for each one a single bash file `slurm_run_i.sh` which indicates the computations configuration, and the srun command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 
#SBATCH -J pltCV
#SBATCH --mem=30G

srun python plotConvergence.py i
```

I am then using another bash file to submit all these tasks, `slurm_run_all.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}:
  sbatch slurm_run_$i.sh 
done
```

This works (50 jobs are running on the cluster), but I find it troublesome to have more than 50 input files. Searching a solution, I came up with the & command, obtaining something as:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --ntasks=50
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 
#SBATCH -J pltall
#SBATCH --mem=30G

# Running jobs 
srun python plotConvergence.py 1   &
srun python plotConvergence.py 2   & 
...
srun python plotConvergence.py 49  & 
srun python plotConvergence.py 50  & 
wait
echo "All done"
```

Which seems to run as well. However, I cannot manage each of these jobs independently: the output of `squeue` shows I have a single job (pltall) running on a single node. As there are only 12 cores on each node in the partition I am working in, I am assuming most of my jobs are waiting on the single node I've been allocated to. Setting the -N option doesn't change anything too.. Moreover, I cannot cancel some jobs individually anymore if I realize there's a mistake or something, which sounds problematic to me.

Is my interpretation right, and is there a better way (I guess) than my attempt to process several jobs in slurm without being lost among many files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [jobs array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) feature of Slurm.

In your case, you would have a single submission file (`slurm_run.sh`) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 
#SBATCH -J pltCV
#SBATCH --mem=30G
#SBATCH --array=1-50

srun python plotConvergence.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
```

and then submit the array of jobs with

```
sbatch slurm_run.sh
```

You will see that you will have 50 jobs submitted. You can cancel all of them at once or one by one. See the man page of `sbatch` for details.

Comment: Thanks, this perfectly answers the question. In my actual case, I'm planning to add string arguments to my plotConvergence.py script, and I searched the array option documentation. By chance I managed to find this post that I did not find before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642029/slurm-sbatch-job-array-for-the-same-script-but-with-different-input-string-argum, that you answered too. I guess I can manage my issue with that; thanks a lot !